# What is the correct command to use pipelines from transformers?

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have transformers installed, as well as huggingface installed, and I had this code running successfully eariler but I don't know what happened now. I had pip install pipelines afterwards but it interfered with the code (so I deleted it)

```
from pipelines import pipeline

nlp = pipeline("e2e-qg")
nlp("42 is the answer to life, the universe and everything.")
```

it now gives me an error of

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from pipelines import pipeline
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pipelines'
```

Comment: Don't you mean `from transformers import pipeline`?

Comment: that line doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try with the latest `transformers` library. Here are other ways to try

```
# Use a pipeline as a high-level helper
from transformers import pipeline
pipe = pipeline("text2text-generation", model="valhalla/t5-base-e2e-qg")
```

Another way

```
# Load model directly
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("valhalla/t5-base-e2e-qg")
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("valhalla/t5-base-e2e-qg")
```

This documentation you can find [here](https://huggingface.co/valhalla/t5-base-e2e-qg)